# How to Handle User Input and Display Calculated Balance in a React Native App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

Can't get the calculated value of the user's balance to work. User inputs the value of their balance on the first page, and the next button is supposed to bring them to a page that displays the calculated balance (The calculated balance should be the user-entered withdrawal amount minus the 0.25 transfer fee, and then subtracted from 20.00). Please help.

I need the second page to display the final result, only if the withdrawal amount - 0.25 is less than or equal to 20.00, or else it displays a message saying you don't have enough in the bank to successfully make the withdrawal. I have tried almost everything I know. Below is my current code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        amount: 20.00,
        inputPageDisplay: 'block',
        resultPageDisplay: 'none',
        message: '',
    };
    
    
    // When Next button is pressed, hide Input page and show Result page
    handleInputPagePress = () => this.setState(state => ({
        inputPageDisplay: 'block',
        resultPageDisplay: 'none',
    }));
    
    // When Go Back button is pressed, hide Input page and show Result page
    handleResultPagePress = () => this.setState(state => ({
        inputPageDisplay: 'none',
        resultPageDisplay: 'block',
    }));
    
    
    selectMessage = (totalAmount) => {
        if (this.state.totalAmount == this.state.amount - 20.00 - .25 || totalAmount <= this.state.amount - 20.00 - .25 ) {
            this.setState({ 
                message: 'You have successfully transfered',
            })
        } else if (this.state.totalAmount >= this.state.amount - 20.00 - .25 ) {
            this.setState({ 
                message: 'You do not have enough funds to transfer',
            })
        }
    }
    
    

    _handleTextChange = inputValue => {
        this.setState({ inputValue });
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ display: this.state.inputPageDisplay }}>
                    <View style={styles.transfer}>
                        <Text style={styles.blueText}>
                            Transfer Balance
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    
                    <View style={styles.balanceBox}>
                        <Text style={styles.amount}>Amount</Text>
                        
                        <View style={styles.numberBox}>
                            <Text style={styles.valueText}>$</Text>
                            <TextInput style={styles.valueText}
                                keyboardType = 'numeric'
                                onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}
                                value={this.state.amount}
                                style={styles.amountText}
                            />
                        </View>
                        
                        <Text style={styles.venmo}>
                            Your Venmo balance is $20.00
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    
                    
                    <View style={styles.debitCard}>
                        <Text style={styles.debit}>
                            Debit Card
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.fee}>
                            $0.25 Fee >
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                        
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.next}
                        onPress={this.handleResultPagePress}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>
                            Next
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
                
                
                <View style={{ display: this.state.resultPageDisplay }}>
                    <View style={styles.transfer}>
                        <Text style={styles.blueText}>
                            Transfer Balance
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    
                    <View style={styles.balanceBox}>
                        <Text style={(styles.amount)}>
                            {20 - (this.state.amount - 0.25)}
                        </Text>
                        
                        <TextInput style={styles.valueText}
                            onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}
                            style={styles.amountText}
                        />
                            
                        <Text style={styles.venmo}>
                            Your Venmo balance is $20.00
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                        
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.next}
                    onPress={this.handleInputPagePress}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>
                            Next
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    
    transfer: {
        backgroundColor: '#0099cc',
        height: 40,
        width: 225,
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginBottom: 'auto',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    
    blueText: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    
    balanceBox: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        height: 275,
    },
    
    amount: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    
    amountText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
    },
    
    balance: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
    },
    
    venmo: {
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    
    debitCard: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 'auto',
        bottom: 10,
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    
    debit: {
        alignContent: 'flex-start',
        margin: 'auto',
    },
    
    fee: {
        alignContent: 'flex-end',
        margin: 'auto',
    },
    
    next: {
        bottom: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#0099cc',
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        marginBottom: 'auto',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    numberBox: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: deviceWidth,
    },
});
```

Comment: Hey can you explain a bit with some images